# Hypernym for various parts of a plant

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, plant-physiology

*Bark, berry, flower, herb, leaves, nuts, plant, resin, seeds, wood*, etc.

These are all — what? *Parts? components? elements? plant forms? divisions?*

I have the sense there may be a more elegant word that nails it, especially since *plant* is itself in the list.

Comment: Parts or components of what? What is the common group they belong to?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Herbs or plants, mostly. I'll clarify the question, thanks..

Comment: @RegDwigh Brilliant revision! The distinction of hypernym/hyponym is a revelation.

Comment: @RegDwighт Sadly, I could not offer a real hypernym, certainly not a word that includes the object *plant* itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, we need to refer to them as **structural components of the plant**.

In regular usage, they are just ***parts of the plant***.

Both the terms are recognized and widely used in literature.

This may interest you: [Plant morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_morphology) (Wikipedia)